# how to import a class named test contained in a package called EDU.student?

Tags: java, class, netbeans, package

**how to import a class named test contained in a package called EDU.student ?**

This was a test question that my teacher gave. I did not understand the question.

P.s please do explain the answer as I'm just learning about classes, inheritance etc.

Comment: `import EDU.student.test;` -> possibly the first lesson in a java base tutorial

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: @Lino @ Andy Turner Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

Im sure hes on about the package name because from past experience I had an issue trying to execute my program using new classes on top of that, my issue was with the new classes added they had to have the same package name.

for example my three classes have package name test. 
When I add new classes i must also add import package test.

This is only not the case when the package is default.